# Как распарсить дату json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу сделать так что бы ответ который приходит с сервера отображался на экране, не не могу найти как это сделать.

```
$.ajax({
    url: theUrl,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})

.done(function(data) {
    alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data );
    debugger;
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {});
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Вот пример того что приходит с `data`

```
{"wrapperType":"track",
 "kind":"song",
 "artistId":909253,
 "collectionId":120954021,
 "trackId":120954025,
 "artistName":"Jack Johnson",
 "collectionName":"Sing-a-Longs and Lullabies for the Film Curious George",
 "trackName":"Upside Down",
 "collectionCensoredName":"Sing-a-Longs and Lullabies for the Film Curious George",
 "trackCensoredName":"Upside Down",
 "collectionPrice":10.99,
 "trackPrice":0.99,
 "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit",
 "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit",
 "discCount":1,
 "discNumber":1,
 "trackCount":14,
 "trackNumber":1,
 "trackTimeMillis":210743,
 "country":"USA",
 "currency":"USD",
 "primaryGenreName":"Rock"}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59799/discussion-on-question-by-----json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По факту уже все распаршено. Все, что требуется - манипуляция с данными:

```
.done(function(data) {
    let message = "";
    if (data.resultCount) {
        data.results.forEach(function(artist) {
            message += "Имя: " + artist.artistName + "; Жанр: " + artist.primaryGenreName + "\n";
        });
    } else {
        message = "ничего не найдено";
    }
    alert(message);
})
```

Смотрим - если есть результаты поиска, то пробегаемся по ним и собираем инфу.

Почитать:

- [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example)

Comment: Не работает почему то

Comment: Опишите, что именно не работает. Я ж не экстрасенс...

Comment: В том то и проблема что я не могу понять, ну вот что пишет в консоле
Uncaught ReferenceError: getRecord is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: Может давай я вам скину весь код, а вы посмотрите что я не так написал?

Comment: @Богдан Залейте на какой гугл драйв чтоли...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Susql6DN-HdjVwWFU3c1c2Mzg

Comment: Удалите строку под красной стрелкой и проверьте что под синей (я обновил ответ) https://www.screencast.com/t/W3sm5KVoi

Comment: Теперь все работает, спасибо вам больше!
не знаю что бы без вас делал.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать `dataType`: `json`, на сколько я помню `jsonp` это не много другое.

Comment: c json не работет так как на сервере другой домен, или может я что то не так понял

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/120336/

Comment: Тогда верно, jsonp нужен, просто это не указали в вопросе